# Redirect a page for a specific time peroid

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a 302 redirect which waits for 18 seconds after redirecting and then goes back to the parent page.

Here is what I have done,

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function (){
 if (document.cookie.indexOf(welcomeCookie) != -1 ||
     document.cookie.indexOf(dailyWelcomeCookie) != -1
 ){
    document.cookie="toURL"+ "=" +escape(document.URL)+";path=/; domain=.forbes.com";
    document.cookie="refURL"+ "=" +escape(document.referrer)+";path=/; domain=.forbes.com";
    this.location="http://www.forbes.com/fdc/welcome_mjx.shtml";
 })();
</script>
```

Comment: Is that the code for the origin or destination page? And what exactly are you asking, how to wait 18 seconds?

Comment: Is the page that you redirect to under your control?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you need to first redirect the user, which you appear to know how to do.  However, once the user is redirected to the target page, that target page will need to have some JavaScript to send the user to the parent page.  Here's some simple JavaScript code that will do what you need based on your code above:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function (){
if (document.cookie.indexOf(welcomeCookie) != -1 ||
    document.cookie.indexOf(dailyWelcomeCookie) != -1
){
    document.cookie="toURL"+ "=" +escape(document.URL)+";path=/; domain=.forbes.com";
    document.cookie="refURL"+ "=" +escape(document.referrer)+";path=/; domain=.forbes.com";

    // wait 18 seconds then go to the specified page. 18000 milliseconds == 18 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
        this.location="http://www.forbes.com/fdc/welcome_mjx.shtml";            
    }, 18000); 
})();
</script>
```